# Секундомер на QT

Tags: qt, c++

Как в QT организовать отсчет времени с выводом на экран? К примеру, секундомер. Не могу понять, как это сделать через QTime или QTimer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ есть прямо в документации по [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QTimer.html)

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
timer->start(1000);
```

В слоте update() можно, например, перерисовывать надпись, модифицировать счетчик, и, при необходимости таймер остановить.

Comment: Это я понял. А как в том же update() получить значение времени, прошедшего с начала отсчета?

Comment: Создайте либо статическую переменную в слоте, либо поле класса. В слоте увеличивайте или уменьшайте ее в зависимости от задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то каждый Qt объект может создавать произвольное число ассоциированных с ним таймеров. Например, вот такой код будет работать

```
class MyTimer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyTimer(QObject *parent = 0);

    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *);

signals:

public slots:
};

    MyTimer::MyTimer(QObject *parent) :
        QObject(parent)
    {
        startTimer(100);
    }

    void MyTimer::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *)
    {
        static int p = 0;

        qDebug() << "tick:" << p++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно использовать QElapsedTimer